# Working on a code but the calculations do not work

Tags: javascript

So I am working on this code and I cannot seem to be able to combine the radio button amounts with the inputted amount in the textbox. The submit button is supposed to calculate. Here is the question, I am suppose be creating this code for.
Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling fee for purchases. Create a Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box;

Include a JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling.

Add functionality to the script that adds a minimum shipping and handling fee of $1.50 for any purchase that is less than or equal to $25.00.

For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling fee.

The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the formula for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which results in a shipping and handling fee of $5.00.

After you determine the total cost of the order (purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box
This is the code I have so far. Any tips would be helpful. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong or how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculate Shipping</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <[CDATA[ */

var  price=[];
var shipping=[];
var total=price+shipping;

function calculateshipping(){
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementByid('ent').value);
    var total = (price <=25) ? price +1.50 : 1.1 * price;
    window.alert("the purchase price with shipping is $" + total.tofixed(2));
}

function calculateShipping(){
    if (price <=25){
        shipping = (price =1.25);
    }
    else{
        shipping = (price *10/100);
    }

    window.alert("The purchase price with shipping is "
    +document.calculate.ent.value);

}

/*]]*/
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name ="calculate" action="">
<p>
Enter Purchase Price
</p>
<input type="text" name="ent" />
<input type="button" name="button" value="submit" Onclick="calculateShipping()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is PHP related.. Or even magento for that matter

Comment: is this correct?  shipping = (price =1.25);

Comment: you want to get the `id` change it: `<input type="text" name="ent" id="ent" />`

Comment: and that is correct: `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your input tag like the comment on your post mentioned:

```
<input type="text" name="ent" id="ent" />
```

Then replace your entire script tag with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculateShipping(){
  price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ent").value);
  if (price <=25){
    shipping = 1.5;
  }else{
    shipping = (price *10/100);
  }
  total = price + shipping;
  window.alert("The purchase price with shipping is "+total);
}

</script>
```

Adding the 'id' attribute gave something for javascript to grab onto when executing the function.  Each time you click, it gets the value of that input element and parses it as a float.

Comment: Isn't this the same things I've said? Also shipping should be 1.5 not 1.25.

Comment: The `1.5` comes from the OP's unused `calculateshipping()` function. Not to be confused with `calculateShipping()` @SpencerWieczorek --- `calculateshipping()` and `calculateShipping()` are `two different animals` altogether. ;-) The OP can change it him/herself.

Comment: According to the task the OP wishes to perform he asked for using a $1.50 handling fee, not $1.25.

Comment: That's nitpicking the answer. If it will make you feel any better, edit the answer and see if it gets accepted. That's entirely up to you. @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you have two javascript methods named CalculateShipping() - how do you determine what is getting executed? Shouldn't it be just one single method CalculateShipping() like this

```
function calculateshipping(){
   var price = parseFloat(document.getElementByid('ent').value);
   var total = (price <=25) ? price +1.50 : 1.1 * price;
   window.alert("the purchase price with shipping is $" + total.tofixed(2));

   if (price <=25){
     shipping = (price =1.25);
   }
   else{
     shipping = (price *10/100);
   }

   window.alert("The purchase price with shipping is " + document.calculate.ent.value);
}
```

Comment: not true: `calculateshipping` and `calculateShipping` are different.

Comment: ^--: Exactly. The OP's methods in using next two identical names is not good practice. Yet `calculateshipping` and `calculateShipping` are `two different animals` altogether. Notice the uppercase `S` in `Shipping` for the second function name.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the uppercase S

Comment: The main problem here seems to be that the `calculateshipping()` with lowercase letters, never gets called. I don't even know why the OP has it in there to start with.

Comment: Plus by not calling the one with the lowercase letters keeps price empty value which would ensure that his shipping cost will always be empty

Answer (score 0):

Seems like quite a basic problem, change `shipping = (price =1.25);` to just `shipping = 1.5;`. Then just calculate the price and alert it:

```
if(price <= 25)
   shipping = 1.5;
else
   shipping = (price*10)/100;

price += shipping;
alert(price);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HMRNB/